# If I delete a game that comes with my PS4, can I reinstall it?

Tags: ps4

My ps4 came with Call of Duty WW2. I deleted it a while ago, so can I reinstall it, or do I have to buy it now?

Comment: Shouldn't it have come with the installation disk? I bought a PS4 that came with a game, and it also came with the disk for the game.

Answer (score 1):

**YES,**

If you purchased the PS4 and had a Digital Download or Disc to Call of Duty: World War 2, you will be able to re-install it at any time.   In the case the game came as a digital download, you can go to the "Library" section of your PS4 and go to "Games" to find the game and re-download it.  If you received a disc for the game, you can simply put the disc in the disc drive and re-install.  Your saved game data should still be on the PS4 if you did not delete that data since the last time playing.

In the case that you don't have it digitally in your Library and do not have the disc anymore, you can purchase a "pre-owned" copy of it from your local game establishment and then use that disc to re-install and continue from where you left off in the game.

I hope this helps, Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can reinstall it if you have downloaded it using your PSN acc; or if you still have the disc. But if you bought a secondhand PS4, you will have a hard time in doing so; since it was downloaded using the previous owner’s PSN acc.